# IJS interop not available in ASP.NET 3 razor pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

While using ASP.NET 3 in combination with blazor, i have noticed that the IJSRuntime is not available.

Including the runtime like this

```
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime;
```

results in this error

> The type or namespace name 'IJSRuntime' could not be found

I can compile blazor templates with no problem and rendering them works fine, so I am wondering why it cannot find the IJSRuntime as that should be part of blazor itself.

The way I have blazor setup to work with ASP.NET 3 was by adding the following lines to my `startup.cs`.

```
services.AddRazorPages();
endpoints.MapRazorPages();
endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
```

Comment: Is that the exact error message you are seeing? Are you using Visual Studio? Which version of VS? Do you have "use previews of .NET Core SDK" enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're using Razor Pages App into which you prerender Blazor Components, right ?

If so, your Blazor Components should be created in a project of their own; that is, a Blazor project, in which case the IJSRuntime service and other services, are added to the DI container by the system.

Once again, Blazor Components should be created in a Blazor project, and the correct configuration will be provided by VS automatically when you create the project. As far as I know, You can't add .razor files to a Razor Pages App (never tried it before), but if this is possible, you should configure your Startup class with all the configuration information produced by a Blazor app. As for instance,

```
services.AddServerSideBlazor()
```

is responsible for adding IJSRuntime service to the DI container:

```
services.AddScoped<IJSRuntime, RemoteJSRuntime>();
```

Hope this helps...